# How to convert from a String to an NBTCompoundTag?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am writing some code for an Minecraft Forge module, where I need to save and restore a TileEntity definition to and from a String.

To convert from  a TileEntity to a String, I can use:

```
NBTCompoundTag nbt = new NBTCompoundTag();
TileEntity te = world.getTileEntity(x,y,z);
te.writeToNBT(nbt);
String nbtStr = nbt.toString();
```

However, to convert back from a String to a TileEntitiy, I am missing the reverse of the toString method (some sort of NBT parser).

```
String nbtStr;
NBTTagCompound nbtTag = new NBTTagCompound();
// this function does not exist
// nbtTag.parseString(nbtStr);
TileEntity te = TileEntity.createAndLoadEntity(nbtTag);
world.setTileEntity(x,y,z,te);
```

I have searched through the various documentation, and am unable to find a function that can convert a String representation to a parsed NBTCompoundTag object.

My question is, what is the method to parse in a string holding NBT?

Comment: Why do you want to deal with it as a string? TileEntity has `readFromNBT` and `writeToNBT` so you can just store the data inside the object and let it be parsed internally.

Comment: I need to be able to read and write the TileEntity NBT to an external text file along with other data, so I have to have it as a string.

Comment: You have to write code. No library method will do this for you, because `toString()` generates a `String` that represents a state. It is not guaranteed that the `String` fully represents the object, only the state, therefore you cannot reconstruct an object from `String`, unless you parse it by yourself. As for how to, you have to write code. Voted to close as too broad.

Comment: I would think that there must exist a String-to-NBT parser function in the Minecraft code somewhere, since the text in books and signs is held as a single string representation of NBT which must then be parsed.  While I could code up a function to do this, I was hoping that there was a documented function to do it already in existance...

Comment: @SteveShipway I checked before I left that comment. Nope. The text in books comes with the string because the string was _part_ of the NBT data and it was extracted properly, and so with the signs, but neither of them uses `toString` - they use specific getters from the `NBTCompoundTag`.

Answer (score 2):

The required function to convert back from a string is in the minecraft `JsonToNBT` class.  It is not deobfuscated by Forge (yet) and so has a rather unhelpful name.

Convert to string representation (actually, JSON format):

```
NBTTagCompound nbt = new NBTTagCompound();
String nbtJsonStr = nbt.toString();
```

Convert back from string to NBTTagCompound:

```
String nbtJsonStr = "{foo:2,}";
NBTTagCompound nbt = (NBTTagCompound) JsonToNBT.func_150315_a(nbtJsonStr);
```

Using this most likely makes the module highly dependent on a specific version of Minecraft, though.